# How to make VirtualBox / Ubuntu work well with Retina display on the Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos, virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox 6.0 and Utbuntu 19.04, and it is showing the screen really small as it doesn't seem to adjust to the Retina display.

So I have to use VirtualBox's View -> Scale to make the screen to a more normal size, but the font appears fuzzy because now it is "forced" magnified (scaled up), rather than native.

Is there a way to make them work well? I already installed the Guest Additions but there is no use.

Comment: tell ubuntu to scale the display to 200% in the preferences?

Comment: I think if you tell Ubuntu to scale up 200%, it is doing the "forced scale up" and it is not native. So whatever is showing on screen, it magnifies it to double the width and height and it is a little bit fuzzy

Comment: Not fuzzy. Try it.

Comment: If you compare the word on the Ubuntu desktop "Trash", with the word "Machine" on the top left part of the Mac's screen, you can see that they are in different resolution. The same with Ubuntu's Terminal app: the text is not as clear as Mac's Terminal app. You can say when text is magnified 4 times and shown on Retina, it is not that bad, but it is still just magnified from low resolution. See https://ibb.co/ftbXPbb magnified 3 times, on the left is Ubuntu, and on the right is Mac native resolution

Comment: Interesting.  And this is with 200% instead of settting the native resolution down?  Then it should be reported as a bug.  I don't have Ubuntu on a hidpi skærm these days, so I cannot confirm myself.